# Xamarin.Android attributes showing "not declared"

Tags: android, xml, mobile, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin and especially xml, but I have run into a problem that I have not been able to resolve with any solution after hours of searching. I am trying to use the "android.support.percent" package to use percent margins on a relative layout. I have installed the proper NuGet packages to support it too. It worked for a little while, but now it has suddenly started giving me multiple warnings and messages throughout the file.

The first error is simply "The 'PercentRelativeLayout' attribute is not declared." This is just the name given to my starting xml tag. Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PercentRelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/percentRelativeLayout"
    android:background="#000000">
```

Second, four warnings appear in the AndroidManifest with a similar message: "The 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:xxxx' attribute is not declared." where 'xxxx' is versionCode, versionName, label, and icon. The manifest file is not very extensive at all:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="MyProject.MyProject" android:versionCode="1" 
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk />
    <application android:label="MyProject" 
    android:icon="@drawable/Icon"></application>
</manifest>
```

On top of all this, there are 4 messages showing that say:
"Could not find schema information for the element 'manifest'."
"Could not find schema information for the attribute 'package'."
"Could not find schema information for the attribute 'uses-sdk'."
"Could not find schema information for the element 'application'."

What does all this mean and how can I get back to actually developing this app?

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out myself, I am not very good at this. The tag must be .

The manifest errors, I don't know, but they seemed to resolve themselves.

Answer (score -1):

The definition is:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

You need to include the proper package name to this layout or else it will not be found.

As for the `AndroidManifest.xml` this looks fine from a first glance.